# Odd gap showing up in Chrome

Tags: html, css, runtime-error

I can't seem to figure out why but there seems to be a gap around the third li element. It shows up in Chrome but when viewing in FireFox, all is good. Anybody know what's going on here?

[Link to view gap...](http://www.martykelly.info/stu40/index.php)

```css
html,
body,
ul,
li,
a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  background-image: url('../images/bg.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  font-size: 0;
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 12.5%;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
ul li {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  /*WHITE*/
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .50;
  width: 14%;
}
ul li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
ul li a {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #000;
  /*BLACK*/
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="keywords" content="" />
  <meta http-equiv="description" content="" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="assignments1.php">Assignment 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="assignments2.php">Assignment 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="assignments3.php">Assignment 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="assignments4.php">Assignment 4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="assignments5.php">Assignment 5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="assignments6.php">Assignment 6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="assignments7.php">Assignment 7</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No gap in Chrome for Mac.

Comment: Can't see any gap either. Maybe post a screenshot?